# Get text between 2 span tags in php

Tags: php

I have to get the text between the 2 span tag but i cant get it.
This is my code

```
for ($idp = 2; $idp <= 2; $idp++) {

$string = "Não foi possível carregar a informação";
$urlp = "http://www.parlamento.pt/DeputadoGP/Paginas/Biografia.aspx?BID=$idp";
$content = file_get_contents($urlp);


if (strpos($content,$string) === false){
    //echo $urlp;
    echo "\n";

    //$ins = "INSERT INTO biografias (idp, urlp) VALUES ('$idp', '$urlp')";
    //$run_ins = mysqli_query($conecta, $ins);

} else {
    echo 'Biografia Inexistente';
    echo "\n";
}
}
```

This is the row of html code that i need to get the text

```
<span id="ctl00_ctl43_g_61a4e0fc_afd7_4b91_ba82_ccfff9f5472d_ctl00_lblNomeDeputado">**Abílio Curto**</span>
```

Thank You.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: If you're just looking for the raw text, without any HTML surrounding it, `strip_tags()` might help you. Otherwise you probably need a regex.

Comment: No need for regex. Take a look at [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) and [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: yes i just need the name betwenn tags

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
$text = '<span id="ctl00_ctl43_g_61a4e0fc_afd7_4b91_ba82_ccfff9f5472d_ctl00_lblNomeDeputado">**Abílio Curto**</span>';

strip_tags($text);
```

Comment: that work but i need a funtion that give the text in different url